# SQL String - remove a substring between 2 occurences

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, substring

I have some strings like :

```
0@11001@2017@308     
0@1@2018@327          
0@200510@2020@3022
```

I need to remove the year value (between last 2 '@'). 
So the results should be like :

```
0@11001@308     
0@1@327          
0@200510@3022
```

Is there a simple query to do it?

Comment: Why you store multiple informations in one column?

Comment: What's your dbms? I would suggest you do that in service layer instead of db

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Something against MySQL?

Comment: It is SQL Server 2012

Comment: What is your sql server version?

Comment: Why are you storing multiple values as strings delimited by `@`?  These should be four columns.  The problems you are facing are a resulting of breaching standard database practices.  Fix that rather than fixing the symptom?

Comment: It is actually a key value computed based on different components

Comment: @Manali I fixed my answer below if you're interested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best thing to do here would be to *normalize* your data, and stop storing multiple data points embedded in a single string, in a single column.  That being said, if you must proceed, we can try using the base string functions to splice together the update:

```
UPDATE yourTable
SET col = LEFT(col, CHARINDEX('@', col, CHARINDEX('@', col) + 1)) +
    REVERSE(LEFT(REVERSE(col), CHARINDEX('@', REVERSE(col)) - 1));
```

[image]

### Demo

Note that this answer assumes that every record would have three `@` separators in it.  If not, then we would have to add additional logic.

Comment: The 2nd substring could be 4 characters too,it could be 0@2005@2020@3022. Is there a way to get the indices of last "@" characters and then remove it?

Comment: This has a danger.  The second item in the list appears to be varying length.  If it is ever four digits long this code will replace that rather than the third item.

Comment: `I need to remove the year value` ... could there ever be _more_ than one year value sandwiched between `@` symbols?  This would seem unlikely.

Comment: I don't know what item#2 ***is***, but sometimes it's 1 digits long, sometimes it's 5 digits long, sometimes 6 digits long.  If it is ***ever*** four digits long, this code will replace the 2nd item in error.

Comment: Ah... just reverse it, reverse it again.

Comment: @MatBailie I fixed it.  I think.  Now the answer makes no assumptions about the _length_ of the year, but rather its _position_ as given by the `@` markers.

Comment: Does use 3*charindex + 3*reverse + 2*left + 1*stringConcatenation.  Using `APPLY` to chain multiple `CHARINDEX` can reduce that somewhat.  I doubt that the cost is significantly different to be noticable compared to the read and write though.  But, so I think, the `APPLY` version is cleaner and easier to read/understand?

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen I am also tasked with handling similar situations and most times I'm unable to affect changes to the database (aka normalization) because the data is coming from many different sources outside of my company (we do alot of ETL work) so I'm forced to come up with workarounds to import, validate and normalize the data. In a perfect world I wouldn't have to do this but . . .

Comment: @MarkKram Yes...which is why this question merits being answered (though many would have voted to close it).  But, we should still be pushing for best database practice here, IMHO.

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE
  yourTable
SET
  col = STUFF(yourTable.col, AtSign2.pos, atSign3.pos - atSign2.pos, '')
FROM
  yourTable
OUTER APPLY
  (SELECT CHARINDEX('@', yourTable.col,             0)) AS atSign1(pos)
OUTER APPLY
  (SELECT CHARINDEX('@', yourTable.col, atSign1.pos+1)) AS atSign2(pos)
OUTER APPLY
  (SELECT CHARINDEX('@', yourTable.col, atSign2.pos+1)) AS atSign3(pos)
```

Comment: I like those solution very much.

Comment: Please don't promote your own answers under my answer, thanks.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen - You mean my comment on your answer?  If you'd like me to remove/move it I apologise and will do so...

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @STRING VARCHAR(50) = '0@200510@2020@3022'

DECLARE @NEED_TO_REMOVE VARCHAR(50) = PARSENAME(REPLACE(@STRING,'@','.'),2) + '@'

SELECT REPLACE(@STRING,@NEED_TO_REMOVE,'') --result: 0@200510@3022
```